VS Code won't show more than 500 outputs for the same cell
I have a model training in an ipynb with 576 different sets of hyperparameters. Each will output training logs and a matplotlib plot. But after 500 I am getting the following output.

How to increase this limit to 1000?
I was expecting 576 individual scrollable outputs separated by graphs

Try to add this to your VSCode settings.json.
ctrl+shift+p >settings (json)
"notebook.output.scrolling": true,
"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 600,

